# How to do mysql_query to pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need help with mysql_query to pdo

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM songs");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $result[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PDO basic query (read [Migrate from the MySQL Extension to PDO](http://www.sitepoint.com/migrate-from-the-mysql-extension-to-pdo/))

```
// Step 1: Establish a connection
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=YourDB", "YourUser", "YourPassword");

// Step 2: Construct a query
$query = "SELECT * FROM songs";

// Step 3: Send the query
$qresult = $db->query($query);

// Step 4: Iterate over the results
while($row = $qresult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result[] = $row;
}

// Step 5: Free used resources
$qresult->closeCursor();
$db = null;
```

Comment: as i do it i get Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array

Comment: @Aivaras use http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php